# Eclipse RCP Application (using p2 repo) Build automation using Ant

Tags: java, ant, eclipse-rcp, p2

We have an Eclipse RCP application which is developed using Eclipse 3.2 (old style update sites) and RCP 3. We have an ant script which builds this application successfully.
Now we have migrated to Eclipse 4.5 (Mars) and here in this Eclipse Mars we are not able to build the product using this existing ant script which runs successfully in case of Eclipse 3.2.
Somehow i could run the existing ant script(as it is without making any changes) but only getting the packaged jars in the build folder and not the .exe file.

Please guide me what changes i will need to make to get the proper build folder or will i need to write new ant script?

Comment: The old ant script builds are no longer supported, [tag:tycho] with [tag:maven] is the current build method (for example see [here](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html)). Why are you moving to a release which is already 6 years and 13 releases old?

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks Greg. So you meant instead of Mars, I should move to latest Eclipse version. Actually i did not think of it yet. I have recently joined this project and people here have already moved it on mars before 2 years but let me see if i am allowed to get it to the latest one.

Comment: As a general rule you should always try and use the most recent release. For example, Eclipse Mars based code will not run with Java 9 or later.